# how to subset a dataframe from a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata

I want to subset a dataframe from a df I generated from parquet files

```
+----+-----+----------+-----+-----------------+-----+-----------+-----+
|year|state|count1    |rowId|count2           |rowId|count3     |rowId|
+----+-----+----------+-----+-----------------+-----+-----------+-----+
|2014|   CT|    343477|    0|           343477|    0|     343477|    0|
|2014|   DE|    123431|    1|           123431|    1|     123431|    1|
|2014|   MD|    558686|    2|           558686|    2|     558686|    2|
|2014|   NJ|    773321|    3|           773321|    3|     773321|    3|
|2015|   CT|    343477|    4|           343477|    4|     343477|    4|
|2015|   DE|    123431|    5|           123431|    5|     123431|    5|
|2015|   MD|    558686|    6|           558686|    6|     558686|    6|
```

I want to keep one "rowId" column and remove other "rowId" columns, and I also want to make the rowId column to be the first column:

```
    +----+-----+----------+-----+-----------------+
    rowId||year|state|count1    |count2 |count3   |
    +----+-----+----------+-----+-----------------+-
        0|2014|   CT|    343477|  343477|   343477|
        1|2015|   DE|    123431|  123431|   123431|
        2|2015|   MD|    558686|  558686|   558686|
        3|2015|   NJ|    773321|  773321|   773321|
        4|2015|   CT|    343477|  343477|   343477| 
        5|2015|   DE|    123431|  123431|   123431|
        6|2015|   MD|    558686|  558686|   558686|
```

My tries:

```
 df.createOrReplaceTempView("test")
 val sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT rowId, year, state, count1, count2, count3 from test)
```

I got error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'rowId' is ambiguous, could be: rowId#3356L, rowId#3368L, rowId#3378L, rowId#3388L, rowId#3398L, rowId#3408L.
how do I do that?
Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map the columns based on the index as following

```
df.map(attributes => 
               (attributes.getInt(3),  
                attributes.getInt(0),
                attributes.getString(1),
                attributes.getInt(2),
                attributes.getInt(4), 
               attributes.getInt(6))).
toDF("rowId", "year", "state", "count1", "count2", "count3").show()
```

Feel free to modify the above statement based on your column data type.

Comment: it says " Reference 'rowId' is ambiguous, could be: rowId#3356L, rowId#3368L, rowId#3378L, rowId#3388L, rowId#3398L, rowId#3408L.;"

Comment: no I need to reduce the rawId columns to only one so that I can do my next operation..

Comment: @Misha, I updated the answer, hope this fixes your issue

Comment: @Misha, I updated the code, I tested the above code in my environment, it works fine, please try this and let me know

Comment: Thank you @naveen marri, i have a bigInt type, is there a getBigInt() in scala? I couldnt find it in the API.. also it seems something is missing, when I tried to use the function, it says the function not finished as if it is not closed

Comment: @Misha sorry a bracket isn't closed, I updated the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174202/discussion-between-naveen-marri-and-misha).

Comment: two of my column types is long, and bigInt, do I use attributes.getLong() and getbitInt()?

Comment: you can get `long` but not `bigint`